# How do you route to a mix of HTTP and HTTPS backends from an ALB Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-alb, ingress, amazon-eks

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in EKS (on AWS.)

In the cluster I have Elasticsearch, Kibana and various other web services.

I would like to set up a single ALB loadbalancer such that:

- Requests to `/_kibana/*` is routed to `service: search-kb-http, port: 5601`
- All other traffic `/*` is routed to `service: web-service-locator, port: 5000`

So I create this:

```
#Note: search-kb-http is provided by Kibana operator
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service-locator
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    company-app: web
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: [SNIP]
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: [SNIP]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: [SNIP]  
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: public-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /_kibana/*
        backend:
          serviceName: search-kb-http
          servicePort: 5601
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: web-service-locator
          servicePort: 5000
```

**Here's the problem**

I prefer to do the SSL termination at the ALB for the main web-service. But the Kibana backend only offers HTTPS. So I need the two different backends to use different protocols in transit.

In doing my research it seems there is an annotation I can apply to the ingress:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
```

But this changes seems to affect the entire ingress.

**Is there a way to specify different transit protocols for different backends?**

Many thanks!

**[EDIT]** I have found a workaround to disable TLS on Kibana in ECK. But the question still stands as to whether this is possible. Thanks!